# Url for search withing Exchange Server OWA

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I can easily create url for searching the Internet for specific term:

```
https://www.bing.com/search?q=example
```

Is is possible to create a similar url for searching my Exchange server mailbox using Outlook Web App? Something like:

```
https://my.exchange.server.tld/owa/search.aspx?q=example
```

**EDIT**

Some of comments asked for target, so here is the clarification:

There is a web-based backoffice system which includes customer's email addresses. I want to provide an easy way to show emails related to this customer in a support mailbox. Adding a link to an OWA search result page seemed a way to accomplish quickly. I can lookup emails either via EWS or IMAP. I wanted to reuse OWA for displaying them instead of reinventing the wheel.

If creating a search link is not possible what would be best alternative approach? I'm thinking about getting message list via EWS/IMAP, showing them and (at least now) redirecting to OWA in order to display the message content.

Comment: Why not use the built in search function for OWA? What are you trying to accomplish that doesn't already exist?

Comment: I'm almost certain that you can't. I just ran Fiddler while looking at an OWA session, within which I ran a search. It doesn't show any search-related URLs that you could isolate. "Search" doesn't show up as its own page, either. It just changes the elements on the OWA page.

Comment: Don't know which is your ultimate target, but I believe you could use Exchange Web Services (EWS) to get search results via HTTP

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I've edited to the post. Now it should be more clear what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use your CRM system or similar to import, download, or otherwise ingest these emails at the point of delivery or receipt, as necessary, and then expose a search function there. This is quite standard in most systems of this sort.

Don't try to bolt more onto an email server than it should be doing.

Comment: +1 for CRM, that was the first thing I thought of after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Forward the mail to gmail and use this url to search your email:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/
(or to any other mail provider with this support).
PS. you really should use https to do this.

Comment: updated sample url to https